# full-text catalog index CONTAINS() doesn't work with numbers

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-catalog

I've just moved databases from one server to another, this query works fine on the old server but now it doesn't work on the new one when I use numbers only in the search:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE  CONTAINS(ProductTitle,'"sample*" AND "7*"')
```

When you remove the 7* it works fine on the new server but it doesn't return anything with it included.  Just tested the same exact query on the old server and it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: You should specify that you're trying to use a full-text catalog index, and verify that the fulltext index is properly built on the new server. Personally, I avoid full text catalogs in SQL Server, especially for something like just a Product Title.

Comment: Tell us about the old server and the new server: are they the same version of SQL Server? What configuration did you copy across?

Comment: I'm using full-text catalog index.  I don't have access to the old server anymore so I'm not sure what it had.  I can't use the LIKE because if user types "7 sample" and the ProductTitle is "sample 7 product", it won't come up which is why I use the CONTAINS.

Comment: What would you use @pmbAustin for something like this? I want it where if user searches for Sample 7, it'll show anything that contains the words 7 and Sample regardless of the order

Comment: You can still use LIKE. Just do a Split String on your search term (splitting on space), and generate a WHERE clause with a clause for each term. This gets into dynamic SQL, but it's a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else ran into this... the new server I moved to had a "stoplist" which for the full-text catalog was for any single letter.  I removed it and everything worked.

Comment: Hey I am running into the same issue, what did you do to remove "stoplist" thanks in advance

Comment: Nevermind I found it under the properties of the FullText, I had stoplist on and toggled it off, re indexed, now all works too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use 'like' instead 'CONTAINS'

Comment: I'm using full-text catalog index. I don't have access to the old server anymore so I'm not sure what it had. I can't use the LIKE because if user types "7 sample" and the ProductTitle is "sample 7 product", it won't come up which is why I use the CONTAINS.