# SQL Server Differences? With Contains

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, contains

I can run this (its a function generated query string from an online advanced search where user can add address, city, zip among other things...):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE
    FREETEXT(pCity, 'Daytona Beach') 
    AND CONTAINS(pAddr, '"*9*" OR FORMSOF(thesaurus, "9")' )
    AND CONTAINS(pZip, '"*32118*" OR FORMSOF(thesaurus, "32118")')   
    AND CONTAINS(pAddr, '"*S*" OR FORMSOF(thesaurus, "S")')
    AND CONTAINS(pAddr, '"*Wild*" OR FORMSOF(thesaurus, "Wild")')   
    AND CONTAINS(pAddr, '"*Olive*" OR FORMSOF(thesaurus, "Olive")')
    AND CONTAINS(pAddr, '"*Ave*" OR FORMSOF(thesaurus, "Ave")')
```

And get the result I'm looking for, only one record: "9 S Wild Olive Ave Daytona Beach Fl 32118"

I copied the database over to SQL Server 2019, copied the thesaurus and ran `EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file 1033;` etc, doubled checked to make sure all indexes where there etc and when I run the same query nothing returns, no errors, just can't find it.

If I run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE
    CONTAINS(pAddr, '"9 S Wild Olive Ave"' )
```

it returns 111 records with this address in there. So the data record is in the table...

**QUESTION**: old server is SQL Server 2014, new one is SQL Server 2019, is there something that changed with contains that is breaking this?

Thanks in advance, just wondering if someone else has ran into something like this or some setting I'm not bringing over that SQL Server 2014 likes and SQL Server 2019 doesn't.

Comment: In your first query, you're using `pAddr`, while your second uses `propAddress`, which is a totally different column. Even if the columns were the same, you have several `AND` conditions, and if any of them fail, you won't find a match. There's no way we can troubleshoot this for you here without a [mre] (including sample data) that reproduces the issue. And no, there is no change in SQL Server that would cause the problem you describe, even if you were using the same exact query and data.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, yeah I get it's difficult, I had typo (fixed) in PropertyAddress... If no change in sql servers then I'm back to square one, same 10 million records on both tables, just different servers... :-( thanks anyway...

Comment: FYI the leading wildcards "*" (like in ```"*Wild*"```) are ignored by fulltext indexes so probably would recommend removing it so it's clearer what the code is doing. See MS doc on wildcards for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sql-wildcards

Comment: Also if you ever want to investigate what data is actually in your fulltext index to, you can use this TVF ```Select * From sys.dm_fts_index_keywords( Db_Id(), Object_Id('dbo.YourTable')```. It really comes in handy when needing to optimize your stoplists and identify noise words

Comment: @Stephan appreciate this, I've inherited this project and trying to clean up code, in old web forms and moving to .NET 6 so these query builders are interesting on what the other dev did and why the wild cards, but hey, yeah removing them query stills works fine. Thanks for the stoplist info, I do want to turn it back on for "noise" words, it was quicker to turn it off for now so the search will work on new server. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

So this has been fixed thanks to another user's question here [full-text catalog index CONTAINS() doesn't work with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838312/full-text-catalog-index-contains-doesnt-work-with-numbers)

Basically on the new server had to click on the properties of the fulltext and toggle the stoplist to Off. Re indexed and now same query works from old server...